# Even without passing a connection string to AzureServiceTokenProvider, i get Must contain 'TenantId' attribute and it must not be empty error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

In my code, I am trying to use Managed Identity to retirve a secret from an Azure KeyVault.

var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

var certSecret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(keyVaultUrl, keyVaultCertParam);

This code works locally for me as I have given my personal account access to the AKV also. However, when I try to run this from a VM which has a managed identity, I get Connection string RunAs=App;AppId={myMSIID} is not valid. Must contain 'TenantId' attribute and it must not be empty.
at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderFactory.ValidateAttribute(Dictionary`2 connectionSettings, String attribute, String connectionString).

I am very confused as to why it asks for tenantid if the connection string hasnt been passed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your VM has the [AzureServicesAuthConnectionString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) environment variable set? This is another way the connection string can be specified. Also, based off the connection string error, it seems like you're on an older version of AppAuth since the tenantID should not be required for that connection string that is specified.